# bypass a load balancer rule

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

i have pod on which an app is running and exposing the port **6006**

this pod is exposed by a service where i have :

```
- nodePort: 30017
    port: 6006
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6006
```

The problem is that the url i use to access this app is based on a LB that only exposes **externalIP:443** and i can't add a new policy for 6006.

My question is how can i do on my pod and/or service to match the pod's 6006 to the LB's 443 ?

Comment: are you using any ingress ? not sure how full setup is. you can create the new ingress which will forward the traffic to service on 6006 and service will forward the traffic to pod

Comment: yes we have the nginx ingress

Comment: With the provided information is not very clear what your setup is, please provide more clarity on your question and include as much relevant information as possible, like the ingress and deployment manifests, the platform where you are running it (GKE, minikube), etc.

Answer (score 1):

change your service type to loadblancer

```
 spec:
  type: loadblancer
  ports:
    - port: 6006
      targetPort: 6006
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

you can also add the option internal if you want to expose your service internally

```
annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: Internal
```